# Web2py tag for space

Tags: web2py

How can I show a space using web2py functions from control.

I have tried like

```
T('test')+'&nbsp;'
```

But this is display like `'test&nbsp;'`.

My requirement is, for proper alignment. I have to append a space with my database value.
So in my controller file I have tried

```
result.field+'&nbsp;' output is dbvalue&nbsp;
result.field+' '      output is dbvalue (without space)
result.field+XML('&nbsp;') output is dbvalue&nbsp;
```

Please let me know how I can append a space from control

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. How would you want it to display? What do you expect the resulting HTML to be, and how do you want it to look when rendered in the browser?

Comment: For the proper value alignment. I have to display my database value with a space append to its right. If I simply append result.field+' ' in the html view this space is not appearing.

Comment: Note that in HTML, a series of spaces are turned into a single space. Same goes with any whitespace character (newline, tab, space, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant that it would display "test&NBSP;'" but with lower-case, it seems that SO "helpfully" converts it when asking the question.

So use this to display the space:

```
T('text') + XML('&nbsp;')
```

You need to call XML on XML entities and HTML markup unless you want it escaped.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I have edited my question. I have tried as you said. But it is not working as I need.

Comment: Just a question, when you say the output is "dbvalue&nbsp;" do you mean that you are seeing the 6 characters &, n, b , s, p, ;? If so, can you post your controller code? Make sure you're returning a dictionary... if you don't return a dictionary and just try to return raw HTML it will be sent with the content-type text/plain and thus will render as text... but it could be something else too, so you should post your controller file or at least the part that contains the function you are working with.

Comment: Also, you mention proper alignment -- if that's the case, you could possibly just use a table to get the alignment, but if you're using a fixed-width font and need some string padding that makes sense. If you're not actually making a whole web page and are just doing some data processing, you could also set the content type to text/plain and just use normal spaces instead of `&nbsp`